# In Angular the Slice pipe breaks my code. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

Okay so i have this component and I am iterating over the data. Without the slice pipe everything is great. When I add the slice pipe to limit the output things take a different turn. Angular send this error **Object is of type 'unknown'.ngtsc(2571)** on the

Here is the Data store at the API. It come back like so, as an Object

```
 
{
    "generated_at": "-",
    "schema": "-",
    "event": {
        "id": "-",
        "scheduled": "-",
        "value": false,
        "timing": {
            "type": "-",
        },
        "season": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "start_date": "-",
            "end_date": "-",
            "year": "-",
        },
        "cycle": {
            "id": "",
            "name": "-",
            "car": {
                "id": "-",
                "name": "-"
            },
            "category": {
                "id": "-",
                "name": "-"
            },
            "type": "-",
            "value": "-"
        },
        "useful": [{
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "value": "-",
            "value2": "-",
            "value3": "-",
            "value4": "-"
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "value1": "-",
            "value2": "-",
            "value3": "-",
            "value4": "-"
        }],
        "venue": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "city_name": "-",
            "country_name": "-",
            "map_coordinates": "--",
            "country_code": "-",
            "values": [{
                "name": "-"
            }, {
                "name": "-"
            }]
        }
    },
    "section": [{
        "locale": "-",
        "value": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "country_code": "-"
        },
        "street_group": [{
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "locale": "-",
        "value": {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "country_code": "-"
        },
        "street_group": [{
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }, {
            "id": "-",
            "name": "-",
            "type": "-",
        }
        ]
}]
}
```

This is the component, where is **.get** the data and then in turn push the data to an array so it becomes **Iterable**.

```
export class LiveComponent implements OnInit {
    allData: any = null;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {
    }
    ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get('http://api.redacted_for_privacy').subscribe(data => {this.allData = [data];});
    }
    }
```

This is the HTML where the iteration works as long as I don't use the slice Pipe.

The error occurs at **{{street_group.name}}** where angular says Object is of type 'unknown'.

```
<mat-tab-group>

<mat-tab *ngFor="let data of allData" label="{{data.event.useful[0].name}}">

>! The part below is broken

<div class="content">
  <mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let section of data.section">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let street_group of section.street_group | slice:0:10">{{street_group.name}}</mat-list-item> 

  </mat-list>
  
</div>


    </mat-tab>
    
  </mat-tab-group>
```

I would like to use the slice pipe to limit the results to 7 items from **street_group** since there are 14. 7 a piece in 2 different objects. But Angular prints the whole 14 in both objects.

Comment: But you have only 7 items in street_group

Comment: There are 2 objects with 7 items a piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely you get this error, because allData is of the type `any` hence all nested fields are `unknown`

In order to fix this just add a typing like:

```
// component.ts
  allData: {
    generated_at: string;
    section: {
      street_group: { name: string }[];
      locale: string }[];
    event: {
      id: string;
      useful: { name: string }[];
    };
  }[] = [];
```

Also note, that the initial value should be set to `[]`. Otherwise the typing should be like so:

```
// component.ts
  allData: {
    generated_at: string;
    section: {
      street_group: { name: string }[];
      locale: string }[];
    event: {
      id: string;
      useful: { name: string }[];
    };
  }[] | null = null;
```

Comment: Exactly. You might want to declare an interface or type alias for the array element type because it has a fair number of fields and very long inline types are hard to read, but this is the right answer regardless.

Comment: I have no control over the data. It's coming from an API. I could only pull the data.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Why is **SLICE** causing such a problem. Without **SLICE** the code works fine. Would anyone like to get paid to help me here ? None of the comments help.

Comment: @soobnaibot this doesn't require you to change the API response at all. It just requires you to fix your type annotation in your component.

Comment: I tried, Now I am getting a whole different error. I am literally lost here. Can i pay you to help me out here ?

Comment: @soobnaibot , template compiler relies heavily on typing especially when it comes to nested ngFor's and complex pipes such as slice.

Comment: @soobnaibot what kind of error you have now?

Comment: This is the error on `this.http.get('http://api.redacted_for_privacy').subscribe(data => {this.allData = [data];});` [**data**] . The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type '{ generated_at: string; section: { street_group: { name: string; }[]; locale: string; }[]; event: { id: string; useful: { name: string; }[]; }; }': generated_at, section, events(2696) .

Comment: @soobnaibot Try ```this.http.get('http://api.redacted_for_privacy').subscribe(data => {this.allData = [data as any];});```

Comment: @Syperia Your solution works and now the Slice pipe works. But still give the other issue where . It does not slice per object. Its goes to both objects and the slices. If I am to say `slice:0:3` . Angular would not slice object 1 only. It would slice 4 from Object 1 and 4 from Object 2. See, Section is an Array that has 2 Objects that both contain a street_group Array.  I would like to slice and retain only 4 from the first street_group array.

Comment: That is exactly how you coded it: for each data.section slice its street_group to 0:10. If you want to slice total data.section street_groups I suggest doing a transformation in map rxjs operator for instance.

Comment: the 10 is negligible. How do I access only the first or second street_group array to Iterate. street_group[0] Index is not working.